# pass value in javascript function along with php

Tags: php

```
echo "
    <table  class='productNeedTb'>
        <tr>
            <td >{$row['O_no']}</td>
            <td style='color:{$statusColor};'>{$row['Status']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Product']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Quantity']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Price']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Place']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Fee']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Dest']}</td>
            <td>{$row['ExpeTime']}</td>
            <td>{$row['OtherNeed']}</td>
            <td>{$row['Req_date']}</td>
            <td><button name='IcanBtn' type='submit' class='IcanBtn' onclick='showHelper(`{$row['O_no']}`, `{$row['Product']}`, `{$row['Quantity']}`, `{$row['Price']}`, `{$row['Place']}`, `{$row['Fee']}`, `{$row['Dest']}`, `{$row['ExpeTime']}`, `{$row['OtherNeed']}` )'>我要接單!</button></td>

        </tr>


    </table>
    <br>
";
```

I wrote an php code but in the last td we have button with a function `showHelper()` which is supposed to pass value to the function and do something else.

and this is thw erroe that I got :
麥當勞大麥克 undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined

I know the problem would be in `{$row['O_no']}`, `{$row['Product']}` the ,here but I just can't fix it.
I tried to pass it without quotes but it sees it as a variable but it's supposed to be string so error occur so I tried to make them all string and using "" or '' cause some sort problem as well

```
if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid']))
            {
                //create a prepared statement

                $sql="SELECT Status, O_no, Product, Quantity, Price, Place, Fee, Dest, ExpeTime, OtherNeed, Req_date FROM productneeds WHERE Status='等待中' or Status='進行中' ORDER BY O_no DESC;";
                $exe=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $exeChk=mysqli_num_rows($exe);
                if($exeChk>0)
                {
                    echo "
                    <table  class='productNeedTb'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>訂單No.</td>
                            <td>狀態</td>
                            <td>物品</td>
                            <td>物品數量</td>
                            <td>物品單價</td>
                            <td>購買地點</td>
                            <td>願意支付跑腿費</td>
                            <td>送達地點</td>
                            <td>期望送達時間</td>
                            <td>特殊要求</td>
                            <td>提出時間</td>
                            <td></td>

                        </tr>


                    </table>
                    <br>

                     ";
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe))
                        {
                            //$p_info=[$row['O_no'],$row['Product'],$row['Quantity'],$row['Price'],$row['Place'],$row['Fee'],$row['Dest'],$row['ExpeTime'],$row['OtherNeed']];
                            if($row['Status']=="等待中")
                            {
                                $statusColor="red";
                                echo "
                                <table  class='productNeedTb'>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td >{$row['O_no']}</td>
                                        <td style='color:{$statusColor};'>{$row['Status']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['Product']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['Quantity']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['Price']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['Place']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['Fee']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['Dest']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['ExpeTime']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['OtherNeed']}</td>
                                        <td>{$row['Req_date']}</td>

                                        <td>
                                        <button name='IcanBtn' type='submit' class='IcanBtn' onclick='showHelper(\" " . $row['O_no'] . " \", \" " . $row['Product'] . " \",\"" . $row['Quantity'] . "\",\"" . $row['Price'] . "\",\"" . $row['Place'] . "\",\"" . $row['Fee'] . "\",\"" . $row['Dest'] . "\",\"" . $row['ExpeTime'] . "\",\"" . $row['OtherNeed'] . "\")'>我要接單!</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>


                                </table>
                            <br>
                            ";
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your attempt was unsuccessful was because javascript saw your parameters as javascript variables hence the undefined error.

To fix your issue, i wrapped the variables around quotes and escaped to prevent them from being seen as javascript variables

```
<td><button name='IcanBtn' type='submit' class='IcanBtn' onclick='showHelper(\"" . $row['O_no'] . "\",\"" . $row['Product'] . "\",\"" . $row['Quantity'] . "\",\"" . $row['Price'] . "\",\"" . $row['Place'] . "\",\"" . $row['Fee'] . "\",\"" . $row['Dest'] . "\",\"" . $row['ExpeTime'] . "\",\"" . $row['OtherNeed'] . "\")'>我要接單!</button></td>
```

Comment: Sir thank you, but when I console.log(all the item) it gives me
15 undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined

Comment: Yeah then that's an issue with your code. Verify that the other parameters have values

Comment: Yeah sir I did some checks and as long as I put the var to the first the first one will have it's correct value

Comment: I just did a test where i used dummy variables to replace `OtherNeed`, `Price` and others and i get their values via javascript. Make sure `$row` contains what it should

Comment: Sir will it matter if $row is something from database, because I think they do have their value since I printed it out in the table and all of them are indeed correct

sorry I'm a newbie~~

Comment: what does `var_dump($row);` return?

Comment: sorry where should I put that?

Comment: Does it give you all the values? I just want to confirm

Comment: should I put var_dump($row ) in console.log()?? or ?

Comment: Yes I I have all the correct value 

<button name="IcanBtn" class="IcanBtn" onclick='showHelper(" 16 ", " 麥當勞大麥克 ","1","150","市區","35","迎曦莊","2020-04-16 12:59:00","123")' type="submit">我要接單!</button>

Comment: the btn will fire a function like this (eventually)
<br>

function helperConfirm(Ono, Product, Quantity, Price, Place, Fee, Dest, ExpeTime, OtherNeed) {
  console.log(Ono, Product, Quantity, Price, Place,Fee,Dest,ExpeTime,OtherNeed);
  let x=document.getElementById("comf_Ono");
  let y=document.getElementById("comf_Product");
  x.innerHTML=Ono;
  y.innerHTML=Product;
}

Comment: I solved it thank you, I forgot to pass more value in showHelper